# RabbitMQ, ресурсоемкие задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x, rabbitmq

Есть frontend приложение на php.
При выполнении определенной бизнес-логики публикуется задача в rabbitMq. Обработчик задачи на python 3.7 pika

Жизненный цикл задачи в воркере:

1. Получил задачу, отправил api во frontend приложение, что взял в работу.
2. Запустил ресурсоемкую операцию.
3. После выполнения отдал результат в api по безнес-логике.
4. Отметил что задача выполнена в очереди RabbitMQ.
5. Отправил результат в api о том что системная задача выполнена или вернул сообщение или код ошибки.
6. Взял следующую задачу.

Вопрос: между 2 и 3 пунктом, задача может выполнятся около часа(больше не наблюдалось). Как исключить такие ситуации, и можно ли при выполнении задачи более определенного количества времени переносить ее в другую очередь? Есть ли вообще какие-либо решения на этот счет?

Answer (score 0):

Решено через модуль

> multiprocessing

для Python3.7

Comment: А можно подробнее?